# How to query MySQL JSON column data for null values?

Tags: sql, mysql, json, where-clause

I'm storing JSON data in JSON type column in MySQL database. Tried to filter `extra_data` column for where `payment_address` is not `null`. Unfortunately couldn't find the right way.

These are the queries I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE extra_data->"$.payment_address" != NULL;
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE extra_data->"$.payment_address" IS NOT NULL;
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE extra_data->"$.payment_address" != "null";
```

For the `extra_data` column, JSON data is like this:

| extra_data |
| --- |
| {"tracking_number": "", "payment_amount": null, "payment_address": null} |
| {"tracking_number": "", "payment_amount": null, "payment_address": "testaddress"} |

How can I query some field in JSON column for null/not null values?

Comment: Can you edit your question, and share some simple data and the expected output

Comment: @SelVazi added the sample data. I just need rows where payment_address is null or not null.

Comment: As soon as you need to start looking inside json field data for WHERE or JOIN predicates, it's time to think about including those fields as part of the actual schema. Performance will be **multiple orders of magnitude** better.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely related to [bug 85755](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85755) which relates to the difference between JSON `null` and SQL `NULL`. Anyway, you can workaround this by using `->>` or `JSON_UNQUOTE` instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE extra_data->>"$.payment_address" != 'null';

SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(extra_data->"$.payment_address") != 'null';
```

In both cases the output is:

| extra_data |
| --- |
| {"payment_amount": null, "payment_address": "testaddress", "tracking_number": ""} |

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMDnEwVxtngqb4hFH44UaS/0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REPLACE` to replace 'null' value into empty value, then get only not empty values :

```
SELECT extra_data
FROM orders
where REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_data, '$.payment_address'), 'null', '')  <> '' ;
```

Result :

```
{"payment_amount": null, "payment_address": "testaddress", "tracking_number": ""}
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wSWZ4V9H9ZQPL9TTJ4r4jp/0)

Comment: thank you for your help @SelVazi, looks like working as expected as a workaround but I wonder if there is another approach without using replace().

Comment: Using string functions on a JSON column is an anti-pattern - especially in a database such as MySQL, which added JSON support long time ago (since version 5.7).

Comment: That's correct @GMB, I should learn more about MySQL's JSON capabilities.